# For JSON Request, asp.net webapi post method , is not getting Request object populated proplerly..all properites coming null

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I have created ASP.NET WEBAPI service. Service has Post method, which has custom class type parameter ( PublishRequest class, XSD generated class from xsd schema). 
PublishRequest class is generated using xsd.exe. we are using XmlSerializer( not DataContractSerializer,    formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;)

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = ..)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("PublishRequest", Namespace =..,
 IsNullable = false)]
public partial class PublishRequest 
{
        ......
    public   ContextInfo Context{get ...;set ...;}

}


[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace =..)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("Context", Namespace =..,
IsNullable = false)]
public partial class ContextInfo
{ 
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Account", typeof(AccountInfo),
  IsNullable = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("EmpID", typeof(string))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Office", typeof(string),
DataType="nonNegativeInteger")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute("ItemElementName")]
public object Item
{
        get
        {
            return this.itemField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemField = value;
        }
}

    /// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
public ItemChoiceType ItemElementName
{
        get
        {
            return this.itemElementNameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemElementNameField = value;
        }
}


}
..... 

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.17929")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace =.., IncludeInSchema = false)]
public enum ItemChoiceType
{

    /// <remarks/>
    Account,

    /// <remarks/>
    EmPID,

    /// <remarks/>
    Office

 }
```

................................

```
[HttpPost]
public PublishResponse Publish(PublishRequest request) {
  ....
}
```

For XML request type, PublishRequest is getting properly deserialized..with all properties populated as per XML.
but for JSON Request type, PublishRequest is not getting properly deserialized, all properties of request coming null. 
I verified json, by calling

```
  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(sJSon, typeof(PublishRequest))
```

this is returning properly deserialized object, with all property set. 
 also

```
  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(sJSon, typeof(PublishRequest))
```

returns proper deserialized object.

I found that for JSONMediaFormatter calls following overload https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/Formatting/JsonMediaTypeFormatter.cs

```
 JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(sJSon, typeof(PublishRequest),
 jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings)
```

I made same call in unit test to aboe overload method, which returns object with all properties null.  So, it seems something in jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings is causing problem to deserializing.
I compared default value of JsonSerializerSettings, with jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.
only property which look different was ContractResolver.
 for default JsonSerializerSettings, ContractResolver is null. For  jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings, it is JsonContractResolver object.

If I set ContractResolver to null in FormatterConfig.cs, json request is getting deserialzied properly.

```
jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = null;
```

### Can any one please guide me, what JsonContractResolver is doing. which causing deserialize problem. what is way to solve this. will this workaround cause any other issue?

while googling for solution, i found this http://json.codeplex.com/discussions/351981
So, it seems problem is with SerializeableAttribute. 
DefaultContractResolver has property IgnoreSerializableAttribute. which if set to true. JSON serialiser/derserialise will ignore SerializeableAttribute. 
But JsonContractResolver , which is derived from DefaultContractResolver, has IgnoreSerializableAttribute to false. so if,  IgnoreSerializableAttribute  is set to true,json serilization/derserilization works proplery.

```
DefaultContractResolver cr = jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver as DefaultContractResolver;
        if (cr != null)
        {
            cr.IgnoreSerializableAttribute = true;
        }
```

This working properly. & issue with json serilzation gone. hope some WebAPI team member reached this question..& guide if this ok? or it will cause any other problem...

Comment: Maybe completely irrelevant, but i ran into some sort of issue when trying to deserialize a JSON ViewModel representation to the ViewMOdel object, where the viemodel properties were marked with [ReadOnly] attribute. Also thought it was a serialization issue. Any change your PublishRequest class has properties marked with [ReadOnly]?

Comment: there is no ReadOnly attribute in PublishRequest class..

Comment: Can you share the class definition of `PublishRequest` and the json you are trying to deserialize?

Comment: @MaggieYing PublishRequest class is generated using xsd.exe, we are using XMLSerializer(not DataContractSerializer).. class is big..i posted part of it...

Comment: My first try, even if I'm not sure of it would be good, would be to set the Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverterAttribute to the default Converter